# Java JTable wont load

Tags: java, swing, hashmap, jtable

I have a  `HashMap<Person, ArrayList<Account>>` and i want a table with all keys ( Persons) from HashMap. The problem is that the table is empty if i try to create it in view, but if i create it in main(with the exact same code) it works and is populated with data. I don't know why.

```
public class App 
{
public static void main( String[] args )
{

    View view = new View();
    Bank b = new Bank();
    Person p = new Person("Name","Prenume", "id");
    Person p1 = new Person("Name2","Prenume2", "id2");
    b.addPerson(p);
    b.addPerson(p1);

    view.personTbl = view.tablePers(b.mapper);
    view.sp = new JScrollPane(view.personTbl);
    view.personFrame.add(view.sp,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    view.viewPers.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

If i create it like this it doesn't work

```
 public View() {
    personFrame = new JFrame("Person");
    personFrame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    personFrame.setSize(400, 400);
    persBtnsPan = new JPanel();
    viewPers = new JFrame("View Pers");
    viewPers.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    viewPers.setSize(400, 400);
    viewPersPan = new JPanel();
    addPerson = new JButton("add");
    editPerson = new JButton("edit");
    viewP = new JButton("view");

    personTbl = tablePers(b.mapper);
    sp = new JScrollPane(personTbl);

    persBtnsPan.add(addPerson);
    persBtnsPan.add(editPerson);
    persBtnsPan.add(viewP);
    personFrame.add(persBtnsPan, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    personFrame.add(sp,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
```

This is the method that creates the table

```
    public static <T> JTable tablePers(HashMap<Person, ArrayList<Account>> map) {
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(
        new Object[] { "Nume", "Prenume", "CNP" }, 0);
    for (HashMap.Entry<Person, ArrayList<Account>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        model.addRow(new Object[] { entry.getKey().getNume(), entry.getKey().getPrenume(), entry.getKey().getCnp() });
    }
    tab = new JTable(model);
    return tab;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got reference problems in that your `b.mapper` in the View is not the same as the one in the main, but nor should it be. But it makes no sense for the View to be handling data like this. You need to pass the *model* into View, directly or indirectly, and then have the view show the state of the model.

e.g.,

```
public class App {
    Bank b = new Bank(); // the model
    //... do things with b here

    View view = new View(b); // pass the model in
    // and then in View's constructor use the model

}
```

Also, if this is an M-V-C program, then your Controller will be listening for changes to the view, and the model, and will notify the concerned entities of the changes, updating the model and the view.

e.g.,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BankModel model = new BankModel();
    model.addPerson(new BankPerson("LastName1", "FirstName1", "id1"));
    model.addPerson(new BankPerson("LastName2", "FirstName2", "id2"));
    BankView view = new BankView();
    BankController controller = new BankController(model, view);
    controller.displayGui();
}
```